# Loading Service account Json key file

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

Google has recently started to give us a Json key file for service account instead of the P12 key file.    I have been trying to get this there isn't a lot of information out there and what info I have seen says this should work.

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive}; 

Stream stream = new FileStream(jsonKeyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes);
```

However its throwing the following exception

> Error creating credential from JSON. Unrecognized credential type .

I have double checked the json key file downloaded two different ones trying to get it to work nothing.

Comment: As per @jon-skeet 's comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75661327/c-sharp-get-credentials-from-google-sheets-api      >         try https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is used for authentication with either the old json file or the .p12 file.

```
public static class ServiceAccountExample
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
        /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="serviceAccountCredentialFilePath">Location of the .p12 or Json Service account key file downloaded from Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <returns>AnalyticsService used to make requests against the Analytics API</returns>
        public static CalendarService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, string[] scopes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                    throw new Exception("Path to the service account credentials file is required.");
                if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                    throw new Exception("The service account credentials file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                    throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");                

                // For Json file
                if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".json")
                {
                    GoogleCredential credential;
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                             .CreateScoped(scopes);
                    }

                    // Create the  Analytics service.
                    return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Calendar Service account Authentication Sample",
                    });
                }
                else if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".p12")
                {   // If its a P12 file

                    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                    {
                        Scopes = scopes
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                    // Create the  Calendar service.
                    return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Calendar Authentication Sample",
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountCalendarFailed", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code ripped from [ServiceAccount.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.cs)

Answer (score 14):

I think you are using file `google-services.json` downloaded from Firebase. This isn't file you need. Process you have to do is:

1. Go to **Firebase Console**
2. Click on **Settings**
3. Click on **Project Settings**
4. Click on **Service accounts**
5. Click on **Generate new private key** button
6. Use file generated by this method.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded a Service Account json key file and tried the same code and it works fine. I was able to replicate the issue if I manually corrupted the "type" field in the json key file. Can you re-download a json key file and try again. Here is what the json key file should look like (sensitive data removed):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": ...,
  "private_key_id": ...,
  "private_key": ...,
  "client_email": ...,
  "client_id": ...,
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you first need to deserialize the stream, at least that what I found at: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/a5288c4493a12791b46f7142efacb83c4fcacf58/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Auth.PlatformServices_Shared/OAuth2/DefaultCredentialProvider.cs#L169

Try it out and let us know.
And yes, we need to improve the documentation, but let's first find the problem and then I'll open a new issue in GitHub with the specific request.

Comment: The file is available now here: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/a5288c4493a12791b46f7142efacb83c4fcacf58/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Auth.PlatformServices_Shared/OAuth2/DefaultCredentialProvider.cs. I updated my comment with the right link