# C# get credentials from Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, google-sheets

I have a problem with get credentials from Google API.
I searched a lot of old topics and can't find solution.

My code looks like:

```
static readonly string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
static readonly string ApplicationName = "Dot Tutorials";
static readonly string sheet = "Arkusz1";
static readonly string SpreadsheetId = "1IEvv4enfouBXrGEVLTKeQNYTJIzQHmRNyKTxKAxEAfg";
static SheetsService service;
GoogleCredential credential;
    //Reading Credentials File...
    using (var stream = new FileStream("secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
            .CreateScoped(Scopes);
    }
    // Creating Google Sheets API service...
    service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
```

Secret .json I downloaded  :

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "1087609048092-hdh5ku57kaamha72o7t3tdtkb62vq5ur.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "excellent-well-151116",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "*********hidden my secret code*******",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

And when I run it I still am getting the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error creating credential from JSON or JSON parameters. Unrecognized credential type .'

I don't know what is wrong here. I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://dottutorials.net/google-sheets-read-write-operations-dotnet-core-tutorial/

My goal is to get values from this spreadsheet into a DataTable:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IEvv4enfouBXrGEVLTKeQNYTJIzQHmRNyKTxKAxEAfg/edit#gid=0.

Comment: The JSON file you've downloaded isn't a credential in itself - it's just a client secret used as part of user authentication. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications for details - unfortunately that tutorial is basically broken.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```
        UserCredential credential2;

        using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(clientSecretsPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential2 = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom },
                    "my@gmail.com", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("LoginCookieStoredHere"));
            }

            return new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential2,
                ApplicationName = "Gmail API Example"
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please note, the email address listed is the UserID whose account your trying to access... however, I don't think it matters since you will have a web browser open and it will require you to login with a google account.

The login is stored in a file 'LoginCookieStoredHere' (I believe this is technically a cookie).  The scope goes where: 'GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom' is